# Flex 3 (Actionscript) query for recordset array for data grid

Tags: php, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flexbuilder

Hey, all. I am building an application in Flex Builder 3. Yes, I know that it has an auto-magic feature to build datasheet, but that will not work. I see many Flex controls, such as combo box, can take an array as a  data source.

My question, therefore, is (1) How do I send the request from my action script to my PHP form to request a record set. (2) Presuming that my dataset is in a PHP assoc array, how do I format it to send it back to Action Script. (3) How do I take the data received from the recordset, and put it inot an actionscript array, suitable for use as a data source.

I can connect to my database in PHP, and query it just fine, so I don't need help with that. For consistency, and humor, lets presume that I have the following data in an assoc array that I pulled from a database.

Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Kirk
        [shirt] => Gold
        [assign] => Bridge
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => McCoy
        [shirt] => Blue
        [assign] => Sick Bay
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => Scotty
        [shirt] => Red
        [assign] => Engineering
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [name] => Spock
        [shirt] => Blue
        [assign] => Bridge
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [name] => Uhura
        [shirt] => Red
        [assign] => Bridge
    )

[5] => 1
)

Comment: Please ignore record 5. It is a boo-boo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it easier to send a request that retrieves the data from the PHP in XML format.  Then inside the Flex application, turn it into an ArrayList and use it with your controls.

Comment: OK, how do I do that without any external libraries?

Comment: Adobe has a pretty good example using the HTTPService component in Flex with PHP example code included:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_2.html

Comment: My boss did not want to add any new libraries. So this was the best way. You are right, the example is pretty good. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into :

http://www.amfphp.org

or

http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-php/overview.html